# How can I seed the iOS simulator photo albums?

Tags: ios-simulator, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary, kif-framework

I've got a suite of [KIF](https://github.com/square/KIF) tests for our app, but one part that I can't work out how to cover is where we use `UIImagePickerController`s.  Obviously I can't check the camera, but I'd like to write a scenario where the user chooses an image from their library.  I know that there's `+[KIFTestStep stepsToChoosePhotoInAlbum:atRow:column:]`, but what I don't know is how to set it up it so that there's a consistent set of images for the test to choose from.  How do I seed the simulator's photo albums?

Comment: Are you able to write a test case for picking the image from gallery using image picker? If yes than can you share a code with me because i;m struggling with that in iOS7.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 different ways (one involves programming) to populate the Photo Library of the iOS Simulator:

- Open Safari in the iOS Simulator, search for some large sizes images in Google, open one and display it in full size. Then do a long press on the photo and choose save. Repeat this with several photos to fill up the library.
- Create a folder on your Mac with the images you want to populate the Photo-Library with. Then write a small iOS application, that iterates over that directory and creates NSData objects from each photo file. Save the NSData object to the Photo-Library using the

  (void)writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:(NSData *)imageData metadata:(NSDictionary *)metadata completionBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock)completionBlock

method of AssetsLibrary.

Comment: The second one sounds good for automated tests - I'll check it out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a project that's working for me:
https://github.com/justin/PopulateSimulatorPhotos

It has proven very good in those cases that you need to reset the simulator again and again or want to test quickly on all the device types.